# Out of range with for loops

Tags: java

I have this code, but in main the for loops the number is out of range how can i have a twelve digits or more in a for loops. I tried with long but it doesn't
work.

```
public class ExcelSheetColumnTitle {

    public static String convertToTitle(long n) {

        if (0 >= n) return null;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        long t = n;

        while (t > 0) {
            long reminder = t % 26;
            if (0 == reminder) reminder = 26;
            sb.insert(0, (char)('A' + reminder - 1));
            if (26 == reminder) t = t / 26 - 1;
            else t = t / 26;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static int titleToNumber(String s) {
        int i = 0;
        while (s.charAt(i) == ' ') i++;
        long res = 0;
        int len = s.length();

        if (i == len) return -1;
        while (i < len) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') return -1;
            res = res * 26 + c - 'A' + 1;
            i++;
        }
        if (res > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            return -1;
        }
        return (int)res;
    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (long i = 142453146368; i <= 142453146368; i++) {
            String s = convertToTitle(i);
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            System.out.print(s + " ");
            System.out.println(titleToNumber(s));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long literal should end with `L` (or `l`). Without the suffix, it is an int literal, and must be within the range of the int type.

Change

```
for (long i = 142453146368; i <= 142453146368; i++)
```

to

```
for (long i = 142453146368L; i <= 142453146368L; i++)
```

Of course this doesn't make much sense in your specific example, since your loop only has a single iteration.

Comment: Note you could also use `l` instead of `L`, if you're too lazy to press shift.

Comment: @Manu That is extremely bad advice. Lower case **l** looks like a 1. `1l` vs `1L`.

Comment: It was not advice. I was only correcting the answer: *A long literal must end with `L`* is simply not true.